# Angular - Blueprint of Component

Tags: angular

I have a component that acts like a blueprint for many components. They all share the same methods. How can I make a blueprint out of that?

I don't want to repeat to methods in all other components. I only want to override a method, if I need to change some of the functionality.

```
@Component({
    template: `
       <datagrid (onRefresh)="loadCollection($event)" (onRowSelect)="loadRecord($event)" (onCreateRecord)="createRecord()"></datagrid>  
    `,
    providers: [CollectionService]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit{

    loadCollection($event){
      ...
    }


    loadRecord($event){
      ...
    }

    createRecord(){
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You may create a Parent class and extend it in your components.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan To extend a class is not something I've seen with angular. So I wasn't sure. I thought I must be solved with DI.

Comment: If you are working in Typescript, check out the [Inheritance Section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: @TrevorHector: No you don't need to, Added answer below with Plunker example. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

Try below,

```
export class BaseComponent { 
  name: string ="";
  someCommonFunction(){
    return `Method called from Base Component from child ${this.name}`
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-1',
  template: `{{someCommonFunction()}}`
})
export class ChildComponent1 extends BaseComponent {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.name = "ChildComponent1";
  }      
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-2',
  template: `{{someCommonFunction()}}`
})
export class ChildComponent2 extends BaseComponent { 
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.name = "ChildComponent2";
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Nm8TIC7djISB92qXMoE?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!